# ASIHTTPRequest POST library

Tags: ios, ios6, http-post, asihttprequest

I really wanted to use ASIHTTPRequest do to its easy and already built library. Since it is old code format and in the project I use ARC it doesn't really work. Are there any unofficial updates to it or is there other open source code out there that works well? I just find it very tedious to go back through this code and correct it and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in place of `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Or just disable ARC for `ASIHTTPRequest`, see @La boa boa

Answer (score 1):

1. If your new project uses ARC, you can disable ARC for `ASIHTTPRequest`. Here's a good answer [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)
2. The creator of `AFNetworking` wrote an adapter in order to ease the transition to `AFNetworking` from `ASIHTTPRequest`. See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking-ASIHTTPRequest

Hope it helps.

Comment: do not use `ASIHTTPRequest`. It is discontinued already and does not support ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/975959

It allows you to disable ARC for certain files and thus allowing you to use ASIHTTPRequest.

I've used it with that library successfully.